# How to call methods from a switch case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

Im trying to implement a menu in my tool. But i couldn't implement a switch case in python. i know that python has only dictionary mapping. How to call parameterised methods in those switch case? For example, I have this program

`def Choice(i):
    switcher = {
            1: subdomain(host),
            2: reverseLookup(host),
            3: lambda: 'two'
        }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda:'Invalid')
    print(func())`

Here, I couldn't perform the parameterised call `subdomain(host)`. Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is because the first two functions are getting called when the `switcher` dictionary is created.  You can avoid that by making all of the values `lambda` function definitions as shown below:

```
def choice(i):
    switcher = {
            1: lambda: subdomain(host),
            2: lambda: reverseLookup(host),
            3: lambda: 'two'
        }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda: 'Invalid')
    print(func())
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch cases can be implemented using dictionary mapping in Python like so:

```
def Choice(i):
    switcher = {1: subdomain, 2: reverseLookup}
    func = switcher.get(i, 'Invalid')
    if func != 'Invalid':
        print(func(host))
```

There is a dictionary `switcher` which helps on mapping to the right function based on the input to the function `Choice`. There is default case to be implemented which is done using `switcher.get(i, 'Invalid')`, so if this returns `'Invalid'`, you can give an error message to user or neglect it.

The call goes like this:

```
Choice(2)  # For example
```

Remember to set value of `host` prior to calling `Choice`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option that is obvious to get correct..:

```
def choice(i, host):  # you should normally pass all variables used in the function
    if i == 1:
        print(subdomain(host))
    elif i == 2:
        print(reverseLookup(host))
    elif i == 3:
        print('two')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

if you're using a dictionary it is important that all rhs (right-hand-sides) have the same type, i.e. a function taking zero arguments.  I prefer to put the dict where it's used when I use a dict to emulate a switch statement:

```
def choice(i, host):
    print({
        1: lambda: subdomain(host),
        2: lambda: reverseLookup(host),
        3: lambda: 'two',
    }.get(i, lambda: 'Invalid')())   # note the () at the end, which calls the zero-argument function returned from .get(..)
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this ....**

```
def Choice(i):
    switcher = {
            1: subdomain(host),
            2: reverseLookup(host),
            3: lambda: 'two'
        }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda:'Invalid')
    print(func())



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    argument=0
    print Choice(argument)
```